# Passing parameter in Execute sql task in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

i have a SP which is accepting file name as parameter.

This SP i want to call through Execute SQL Task In SSIS (using 2008)

But my problem is each time filename is got changed. how to handle this kind of scenerio.

Please help me, as i am pretty new to SSIS

SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Xml_FULL_insert]

@XMLFileName NVARCHAR(256)

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(max)

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tblFile', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.tblFile;

CREATE TABLE dbo.tblFile (xmldata XML)

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO tblFile(XMLData) SELECT CONVERT (XML, 
BulkColumn,2) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK '''+@XMLFileName+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS     
x;'

 EXEC (@Query) 


COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY

END
```

i followed the below step:-

1. declare variable with full file path in a value. (Variable Name: Filename )
2. calling SP from Execute SQL TASK EXEC [Xml_FULL_insert] ?
3. PARAMETER Passing :

Variable name: Filename
Direction: Input
Dtattype VARCHAR
Parameter Name: 0
length: 50

whenever filename is differ than the specified in the value of variable, the package failed.

Though file structure is same.

**my variable have value (D:\SSIS_Packages\AutoGrade.xml) full path where file name is ACES_2015.10_AutoGrade.xml
and in a same folder  new file appear as mynewfile.xml. package fail inspite of parameter mapping**

do i need to do some changes in SP? Please suggest if possible.

Comment: U will need working with User variables which pass value to parameter of stored procedure . Check this link https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: @mhasan: in my sql statement i have passed like

EXEC dbo.Xml_FULL_insert ?

In Parameter mapping

Variable name: Filename
Direction: Input
Dtattype VARCHAR
Parameter Name: 0
length: 50

in variable

Path: D:\SSIS_Packages\*.xml still getting error like. "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly. Please help

Comment: May anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Is there a reason you limit it to 50 characters in SSIS, but allow 256 characters in SQL?  Are any of the file names (including the full path) you are passing longer than fifty characters?

Answer (score 0):

change the parameter name from parameter0 to the actual variable name in the ssis package example in your case it should be this
varible name:filename
so in your parameter mapping change it from parameter0 to @filename.